# Left and Right align text on the same line

Tags: html, css

Following is displaying two horizontal lines above the text. What I need is one horizontal line above the text and one below the text:

```css
.alignleft {
  float: left;
}

.alignright {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:800px;">
  <hr />
  <p class="alignleft">To Left: 1024-0038</p>
  <p class="alignright">To Right: 01-15-131194</p>
  <hr />
</div>
```

**Display**: One `hr` should display below the text and should be same width as the other one covering the entire div width.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily maintain the alignment, and replace the `<hr>` elements by using the div's border, looks a bit cleaner:

```html
<style>
  div {
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 800px;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <p>To Left: 1024-0038</p>
  <p>To Right: 01-15-131194</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @G-Cyr Actually what `@BrandonBrickyKerr` is suggesting is what I am after. But I see your point as well since post did not specify what exactly my goal is. Also, thank you for editing my post - it's more readable now.

Comment: @BrandonBrickyKerr I made a small change by using `div.myClass {...}` and then `<div class="myClass">...</div>`. This was to avoid other div's getting effected by your suggested style. But you answered what I asked (thank you). This comment is just for the benefit of other readers.

Answer (score 4):

Please try the following:

```css
.alignleft {
    float: left;
}

.alignright {
    float: right;
}
hr {
clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:800px;">
    <hr />
    <p class="alignleft">To Left: 1024-0038</p>
    <p class="alignright">To Right: 01-15-131194</p>
    <hr />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The floats need to be cleared. There are many different ways to do this. One of them is:

`<hr style="clear: both"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Use a clear:both after the text. Like so:

```
<style>
.alignleft {
    float: left;
}

.alignright {
    float: right;
}
.clear{
clear:both;
}
</style>
<div style="width:800px;">
    <hr />
    <p class="alignleft">To Left: 1024-0038</p>
    <p class="alignright">To Right: 01-15-131194</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <hr />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, float doesn't do what you think it does.

Second, try this:

```
  #container{
      width:100%
      }
    .alignleft {
      width:50%;
      float:left;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .alignright {
      width:50%;
      float:left;
      text-align: right;
    }
   hr{
     clear:both;
    }
```

functional example: https://jsfiddle.net/catbadger/0d144khk/1/